# How to customize the logs using Serilog in Web API c#

Tags: c#, .net, logging, asp.net-web-api, serilog

I need to create a logs in JSON format my web API project with below format.

```
{
   "LEVEL":"ERROR",
   "TIMESTAMP":"2023-06-07 14:07:59,983",
   "CALLER" : "CLIENT NAME",
   "EVENT_NAME":"WHICH METHOD CALLED HERE",
   "ERRORID":"10001",
   "MESSAGE":"INVALID REQUEST/REQUEST COMPLETED"
 }
```

Below is my appsetting.json file.

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": ["Serilog.Sinks.Console"],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext"],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
          "outputTemplate": "[{Level}][{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}] Message:{Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

My logConfig.cs file is

```
public static void ConfigureSerilogServices(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .CreateLogger();                   

        }
```

I can see few value from serilog on console such as timestamp, level, message but I am not sure how to convert it into json format and add few runtime values

Comment: Note that "a bunch of log messages concatenated together" is not valid JSON syntax, even if each individual log message is well-formed JSON.

Comment: @BenVoigt is there way to implement what I want?

Comment: You could write your own wrapper for logger, which will allow you to create a custom json object from the message, which you then pass to serilog logger..

Comment: @Tanuki not sure how to do it. Can you please point to some example please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can show how I have implemented custom wrapper for my own use case, you can use it as an example of writing your own Log wrapper.

My use case is that I wanted to prefix every log message with File and method name of where the log came from.

Program.cs

```
LogRegister.CreateLogger(Constants.AppInfo.AppName, Constants.LogFilePath);

try
{
    ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
    ...
    Application.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "Error setting up ... service. Exiting application");
}
finally
{
    LogRegister.DisposeLogger();
}
```

LogRegister.cs:

```
public class LogRegister
{
    public static void CreateLogger(string appName, string logFilePath)
    {
        var outputTemplate = "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] [{CallerFileName}.{CallerMethodName}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}";
        Serilog.Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.File(logFilePath, rollOnFileSizeLimit: true, fileSizeLimitBytes: 1_048_576, outputTemplate: outputTemplate)
            //.WriteTo.EventLog(appName, manageEventSource: true, outputTemplate: outputTemplate, logName: appName, restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .CreateLogger();
    }

    public static void DisposeLogger()
    {
        Serilog.Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}
```

Notice `[{CallerFileName}.{CallerMethodName}]` above. That is what I am injecting.
In your case you may want to replace the whole line with your placeholder, like this: `var outputTemplate = "{MyJsonMessage}";`

The wrapper `Log.cs`:

```
// We have a Log wrapper in a separate file so that we could enrich all messages with ClassName and MethodName in an efficient non-reflective way.
// Unfortunately there is no simple and native way to do this.
// That does mean that we need to wrap every single logging method we plan on using such as Information or Error.
public static class Log
{
    private static ILogger GetLogger(string sourceFilePath, string memberName, int sourceLineNumber)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sourceFilePath);
        var enricher = new ClassAndMethodContextEnricher(fileName, memberName, sourceLineNumber);
        var logger = Serilog.Log.Logger.ForContext(enricher);
        return logger;
    }

    public static void Debug(
        string message,
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        var logger = GetLogger(sourceFilePath, memberName, sourceLineNumber);
        logger.Debug(message);
    }

    public static void Information(
       string message,
       [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
       [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
       [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        var logger = GetLogger(sourceFilePath, memberName, sourceLineNumber);
        logger.Information(message);
    }

    public static void Information<T0>(
        string message,
        T0 p0,
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        var logger = GetLogger(sourceFilePath, memberName, sourceLineNumber);
        logger.Information(message, p0);
    }

    public static void Information<T0, T1>(
        string message,
        T0 p0, T1 p1,
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        var logger = GetLogger(sourceFilePath, memberName, sourceLineNumber);
        logger.Information(message, p0, p1);
    }

    // example of calling methods with multiple parameters (for structured logging)
    public static void Information<T0, T1, T2>(
        string message,
        T0 p0, T1 p1, T2 p2,
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        var logger = GetLogger(sourceFilePath, memberName, sourceLineNumber);
        logger.Information(message, p0, p1, p2);
    }
    
    public static void Warn(
       string message,
       [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
       [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
       [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        var logger = GetLogger(sourceFilePath, memberName, sourceLineNumber);
        logger.Warning(message);
    }

    public static void Error(
        Exception ex,
        string message,
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        var logger = GetLogger(sourceFilePath, memberName, sourceLineNumber);
        logger.Error(ex, message);
    }

    public static void Error(
       string message,
       [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
       [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
       [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        var logger = GetLogger(sourceFilePath, memberName, sourceLineNumber);
        logger.Error(message);
    }

    public static void Fatal(
       string message,
       [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
       [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
       [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        FatalAction();

        var logger = GetLogger(sourceFilePath, memberName, sourceLineNumber);
        logger.Fatal(message);
    }

    public static void Fatal(
        Exception ex,
        string message,
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        FatalAction();

        var logger = GetLogger(sourceFilePath, memberName, sourceLineNumber);
        logger.Fatal(ex, message);
    }

    private static void FatalAction()
    {
        Environment.ExitCode = -1;
    }
}
```

ClassAndMethodContextEnricher.cs:

```
public class ClassAndMethodContextEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    public ClassAndMethodContextEnricher(string callerFileName, string callerMethodName, int callerLineNumber)
    {
        CallerFileName = callerFileName;
        CallerMethodName = callerMethodName;
        CallerLineNumber = callerLineNumber;
    }

    public string CallerMethodName { get; protected set; }
    public string CallerFileName { get; protected set; }
    public int CallerLineNumber { get; protected set; }
    public static string CallerFileNamePropertyName { get; } = "CallerFileName";
    public static string CallerMethodNamePropertyName { get; } = "CallerMethodName";
    public static string CallerLineNumberPropertyName { get; } = "CallerLineNumber";

    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(new LogEventProperty(CallerFileNamePropertyName, new ScalarValue(CallerFileName)));
        logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(new LogEventProperty(CallerMethodNamePropertyName, new ScalarValue(CallerMethodName)));
        logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(new LogEventProperty(CallerLineNumberPropertyName, new ScalarValue(CallerLineNumber)));
    }
}
```

Usage:
Just use `Log.` anywhere you want in the application. No need to inject anything:

```
Log.Information("Starting Service");
Log.Debug("Error getting response from server.");
Log.Error(message);
Log.Error(ex, message);
Log.Fatal(ex, "Error in the main .. service. Exiting application");
```

In your case you will need to write your main logic for creating and injecting JSON in the Enricher class.
In reality there are many ways to inject your own custom Message wrapped as json.
My Log wrapper is perhaps too complex for your needs, but it is one way. If you want easier way you will need to dig deep into Serilog bowels for that.

Good luck.